# How do i implement select and highlight text in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I am working on eBook reader app and I need to implement select and highlight feature like implemented in Amazon-kindle, kobo,moon+ reader etc.

I tried with WebView as we can select text in 2.3 and later versions of android OS on long touch event. I am not getting the window.getSelection() object so **my JavaScript is not highlighting the text.**

This is possible, as other apps have implemented this feature.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there a special API I need to use?

[image: here is a screen capture from kindle app.]

Comment: Have you got any solution or any improvements?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this open source project [here](https://github.com/btate/BTAndroidWebViewSelection)

It is a wonderful work for select and copy in android webview.