# Detecting selection changes in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, selection

I was able to get the selected text using the following method:

```
webview.evaluateJavascript("(function(){return window.getSelection().toString()})()",
    new ValueCallback<String>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String value)
        {
            selected = value;
            Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
        }
    }
);
```

And I detect the first selection using when the motion event detected by the `onTouchEvent` is `ACTION_UP`.

```
webview.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
           //webview started selection a word
        }
    }
});
```

My problem is to be able to detect when the selection changes using the handlers. Unfortunately `ACTION_MOVE` and `ACTION_DOWN` are not getting called while changing the selection using the default selection handlers.

Kindly note that when I use the `ActionMode CallBack` function, the default selection stops working.

Comment: [Have a look on this link. It might help you.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8656395/how-do-i-implement-select-and-highlight-text-in-android)

Comment: Thank you, I already found a work around.

Comment: Please, can you add your "workaround" as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to mange the touches try letting the system do it for you:

[How to get the selected text of webview in ActionMode override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804100/how-to-get-the-selected-text-of-webview-in-actionmode-override)

```
@Override
public void onReceiveValue(String value)
{
    Log.v(TAG, "SELECTION:" + value);
}
```

with possibly.... [selection change ?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/selectionchange)
:)